Does QF.SE scope include questions by/for students?
Maybe not undergrads (though 4th year finance majors do the same essential topics as MBAs).
Basically, should we allow questions that an MBA or first year master's student might ask?
Not homework questions, but ones to understand concepts.

Gee, I thought at first from the topic you want students excluded from the community. ;-)

Absolutely, yes.  
The only kinds of questions we want to avoid are typical off-topic stackoverflow questions (subjective, lists, overly-general) and questions that are too high-level/introductory (e.g. "how can I get started with trading bonds"?).  

I agree we should allow student type questions.  
